# How to handle filter in Angular expression

Tags: angularjs

Please have a look at below code

Json object

```
namelist = [{name: "Mayur" , checked : true }, { name: "Rayum" , checked : false }]
```

In HTML i want to show number of items which are checked true , for above Json object count should be 1.

```
{{namelist.length}} // gives me total count 
//can we do something like below 
{{ namelist.length | filter {checked:true} }}
```

which we give me only count of the filtered count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{{ (namelist | filter: { checked: true }).length }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `{{ (namelist | filter:{checked:true}).length }}`

You can read about filters [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)